# How to load rowlist values dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am creating application in MVC 4 jqgrid, i want to set rowlist based on the data size or user option(setting the value in the web.config key,value).I tried to pass values using function but i am getting values in dropdown like this.please help me.

**code:**

```
Method;
          function setRowList() {
                var rownum = "[5,10]";
                return rownum;
            }
        MY grid:
                $("#ApplicationDetailsTable").jqGrid({
                    url: '@Url.Action("AppListDetails", "JQGridHome")',
                    datatype: 'json',

                    colNames: ["no1", "name", "phone"],
                    colModel: [
                        { name: "no1", index: "no1", width: 40, align: "left", stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'], value: categoriesStr } },
                        { name: "name", index: "name", width: 100, align: "left" },
                        { name: "phone", index: "phone", width: 200, align: "left" }
                    ],
                    width: 550,
                    loadonce: true,
                    height: 200,
                    toppager: false,
                pager: $("#JQGridPaging"),
                    rowNum:4,
                rowList: setRowList(),
                    viewrecords: true,
                    caption: "A Basic jqGrid - Read Only",
```

**image**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `rownum` as a **string** rather than **array**.

Test changing that line for:

```
 var rownum = [5,10]; // Quotes ripped out.
```

So, when the jQuery function to display the `rownum`, it is **iterating upon a string**, which has the characteristic that is like an array but **every character** is considered as an **array element**.

Comment: U r right it is working.But if i want to get this value from the controller(MVC4) what type i should return array or string Code:     public Array or string setRowList()
        {
             var  r= [5,10,15,20];
            return r;
        }

Comment: @Prathiesh: Well, it makes sense that you should return Array type. Test it and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The option `rowList` will be used only once during creating of jqGrid. So **to change it dynamically** one need replace all `<option>` elements of `<select class="ui-pg-selbox">` which you can find inside of the pager (or the pagers if you use both `toppager` and the `pager`). If you change the value of selected option of the list and you want that jqGrid refresh the content you should trigger `change` event in the `<select class="ui-pg-selbox">`.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ChangeRowList.htm) demonstrate the above approach. The grid will be created with `rowList: [5, 10, 20]` and then it will be changed to `rowList: [2, 3, 10, 100]` and the option `3` will be marked as `selected`:

```js
$("#pager").find(".ui-pg-selbox")
    .html('<option role="option" value="2">2</option>' +
          '<option role="option" selected="selected" value="3">3</option>' +
          '<option role="option" value="10">10</option>' +
          '<option role="option" value="100">100</option>')
    .trigger("change");
```

It's clear that one can build `<option>` list dynamically. I wanted just mostly clear show what should be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it directly as `rowList:[5,10],` It takes not a string but an array as its value to be assigned. You can view an example [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid).

Comment: In my question i mentioned like dynamically i want to get the rowlist not static assignment.